# Selecting exact row information and adding it to a text field from oblist

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, java-8

I have a program that is basically a task manager, it takes information from SQLite Database. it has 5 info fields (UID, Date, CreatedBy, Category, Task). In order to populate the table view I use class Model Table.

Controller

```
    @FXML public TableView<ModelTable> taskManagerView;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_UID;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Date;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_CreatedBy;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Category;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Task;

    ObservableList<ModelTable> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public FilteredList<ModelTable> filteredOblist = new FilteredList<>(oblist, s -> true);

 try{
            Connection conn = 

    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://Location\\");
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs =statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TaskManagerData");

                while (rs.next()){
                    oblist.add(new ModelTable(rs.getString("UID"), rs.getString("Date"), rs.getString("CreatedBy"), rs.getString("Category"),rs.getString("Task")));
                }

            }catch (SQLException e){
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("DB Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("DB Connection Failed");
                alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            col_UID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("UID"));
            col_Date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Date"));
            col_CreatedBy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("CreatedBy"));
            col_Category.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Category"));
            col_Task.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Task"));

            taskManagerView.setItems(filteredOblist);


ModelTable gettingTask =taskManagerView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            detailedTask.setText(gettingTask.getTask());
```

Model Table:

```
public class ModelTable {

    String UID, Date, CreatedBy, Category, Task;


    package Controllers;

public class ModelTable {

String UID, Date, CreatedBy, Category, Task;

public ModelTable(String UID, String date, String createdBy, String category, String task) {
    this.UID = UID;
    Date = date;
    CreatedBy = createdBy;
    Category = category;
    Task = task;
}



public String getUID() {
    return UID;
}

public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return CreatedBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    CreatedBy = createdBy;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return Category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    Category = category;
}

public String getTask() {
    return Task;
}

public void setTask(String task) {
    Task = task;
}

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="488.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.TaskManagerController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="320.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="3.0">
         <children>
            <MenuBar layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Entry" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <TextField fx:id="filter_uid" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="62.0" promptText="UID" />
            <TextField fx:id="filter_created" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="98.0" promptText="Created By" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="filter_date" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="98.0" onAction="#dateFilter" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Date" />
            <TextArea fx:id="detailedTask" editable="false" layoutX="348.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="252.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="348.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="radioHomework" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="79.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonOne" text="Homework" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="radioMaintenance" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonTwo" text="Maintenance" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="radioOther" layoutX="262.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonThree" text="Other" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="radioNull" layoutX="262.0" layoutY="79.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonFour" text="Show All" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="326.0" style="-fx-alignment: CENTER;" text="FILTERS" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children></AnchorPane>
      <TableView fx:id="taskManagerView" layoutY="166.0" prefHeight="282.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="166.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="col_UID" prefWidth="70.0" text="UID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="col_Date" prefWidth="100.0" text="Date" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_CreatedBy" prefWidth="90.0" text="Created By" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_Category" prefWidth="100.0" text="Category" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_Task" prefWidth="239.0" text="Task" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <ButtonBar layoutY="360.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        <buttons>
          <Button fx:id="addTask" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addTaskFunction" text="Add Task" />
            <Button fx:id="exportBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#export" text="Export" />
            <Button fx:id="backToMainMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#backButton" text="Back" />
        </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My question is how can i have it so my program when i select for example UID 7 (when the program is running) from the table view the information from "Task" appears in a text area in the program. Currently

[image: Example]

Hopefully this was understandable.

Thank you.

Comment: @fabian I attempt to do a test but i get an exception and the program won't run. `String test = taskManagerView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getTask();
        System.out.println(test);`

Comment: I have now tried from another post I found but it still does not work `ModelTable gettingTask = taskManagerView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        detailedTask.setText(gettingTask.getTask());`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. Which you were already advised at least once in a former question - why don't you comply? You _must_ learn to post answerable questions (naming conventions improve readability enormously and thus help in communication between you and potential helpers) to make them useful to all - current and future readers ...

Comment: @kleopatra I have updated original post so I comply with Minimal, Complete and Verifiabale point. Regarding naming conventions I have read them and apart from naming columns col_smth and having column definitions start with capital letters (like classes). are there any other mistakes, because I am unable to find according to the naming convention article I read.

Comment: PropertyValueFactory is looking reflectively for properties following api and naming conventions (mininum are either setters/getters  or exposing the property, you show neither - actually I'm wondering why you see anything in your table ;) - so your code is not complying to the __C__ (apart from missing the fxml) It's not doing much for the __V__ because a) it doesn't show how you listen you the table's selection state  b) nobody but you has access to your local db. As to __M__ I can only guess (just the table, its wiring details) - and it's not even an example

Comment: as to conventions: why don't you fix the abberrations you found ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection happens after the scene is displayed. If retrieved before (e.g. in the `initialize` method), the `selectedItem` property is null. Add a listener to the property to do the updates instead:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    taskManagerView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null) {
            textArea.setText("");
            // TODO: clear other controls
        } else {
            textArea.setText(newValue.getTask());
            // TODO: set values to other controls
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: _selection happens after the scene is displayed_ hmm .. not necessarily: selection state can be well be initiated before displaying as we know ;) (probably not done in the OPs context, but then the listener is missing as other details...)